# Bash: how do i choose rows from a file that have particular value in the column

Tags: linux, bash, command-line

I have a huge file that I need to analyze. What I want to do is separate those rows that have certain values in a certain column. So, its like choosing only those data that belong to a certain category. How can this be accomplished with a simple bash commnand or script.

For example, I want to separate only those rows which have values 1, 2 3 or 4 in the 8th column. The file is space delimited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use awk as:

```
awk '$8 == 1 || $8 == 2 || $8 == 3 || $8 == 4' file
```

Comment: How about if the file is gzipped and I need to gunzip -c file | ... ? I couldn't run the awk method in pipe.

Comment: In case the input file is gzipped : gunzip -c input.gz | awk 'BEGIN { FS="\t" }$5 == "en" || $13 == "en"'  | gzip > output.gz

Answer (score 4):

Yet another AWK answer:

```
awk '$8 ~ /1|2|3|4/' inputfile
```

Answer (score 3):

Use awk:

```
awk '$8 >= 1 && $8 <= 4' your_file.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

Yet another awk answer.

```
awk '$8 ~ /[1-4]/' file
```

But, just for some variety, a bash answer

```
while read line ; do
    fields=($line)
    [[ ${fields[7]} =~ [1-4] ]] && echo $line
done < file
```